# How to efficiently test mapstruct spring mapper?

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, mapstruct

I've created some mapstruct mapper annotated with spring constructor injection. I know in the test I can autowire the mapper with `springboottest`, but it seems very heavy and the loading speed is very slow. Can I get the mapper without initializing the spring context? Is this good practice?

Answer (score 1):

You can always get a mapper by means of `Mappers.getMapper(MapperClass.class)`. However, the problem arises when that mapper uses other mappers.

When using other mappers (`@Mapper.uses`) you might also want to use (`@Mapper.injectionStrategy`) and use constructor injection. Since mappers are stateless by design, you could write some reflective code yourself to construct a mapper with all its dependent `uses` mappers.

Comment: Do you mean I have to instantiate manually the mapper including any injection chain?

Comment: Yes. If you don't use frameworks during test to arrange injection, you need to use reflection (that is also what `Mappers.getMapper` does. I would recommend to do this only in unit test. For testing, checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61398218/how-to-efficiently-test-mapstruct-spring-mapper as well.

Comment: oops.. Sorry, wrong stuff under my paste button.. Here's the proper link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60986556/how-to-tests-and-mock-mapstruct-converter